# How to get rid of a right gap in mobile screen

Tags: html, css

I have set the `@media only screen` in my website. But when I open it in my phone, there is an annoying gap at the right edge, which might be an area of the scroll bar on the desktop, as attached screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVyIb.jpg

For some browsers, this gap is visible at first launch, for some others, it's not visible at first launch but you can see it by scrolling to the right a bit.
For some browsers, it affect the top navigation bar, but for some it's not.

How can I get rid of this gap.

My code is at https://www.ayutthayabusmap.com

Regards.

Comment: Please can you post relevant code in the question. Also, the website displays fine for me.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't post it because I don't know where is the problem on the page.